# Which option best for Upgrade a SiteCollection with new content database

Tags: 2013, 2016, upgrade-sharepoint

In below which options are suitable to upgrade a SharePoint 2013 SiteCollection to SharePoint 2016 here I don't want to upgrade the existing database but create a new content database in SharePoint 2013 Farm and Upgrade it to SharePoint 2016

1. Backup-SPSite and Restore-SpSite
2. Move-SPSite
3. Copy-Site

I restored Prodcution content database in development environment

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the move-spsite but only draw back is you have to reset IIS after running that command. If IIS reset is not a problem or plan it after hours then this one is good choice.

Alternatively, i would go with backup and restore method.

Comment: If I create new web application & content database is back up and restore is a good option?

Comment: within same farm or new farm? within same farm no need to create  new web application, just simply backup & store site collection in new db within same web application. after that move that db to new farm and upgrade it

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have is `Move-SPSite` to a new database. It is not supported to use `Backup-SPSite` and restore from 2013 to 2016 with `Restore-SPSite`.

Comment: you mean, we cant move a site collection into own database using backup & restore method?

Comment: You can't use `Restore-SPSite` to transfer the site to a new version of _SharePoint_.

Comment: that i know but questions is what is best method to move site into own database after that upgrade that database.  backup and restore a site into new database within same version. is it not supported?

Comment: if I use  Move-spite there is no need to upgrade the 2013 content DB to 2016?